# A terminology to analysts

Tags: calculus, limits, logic

When analysts say "$\epsilon$ (or whatever greek symbol) can be chosen arbitrary small", do they really just mean we can take $\epsilon = 0$ or $\epsilon \to 0$ later?

When I asked myself this question, I immediately began doubting my understanding of limits.

That is $\forall \epsilon>0 ,\exists \delta > 0 :|x-a|<\delta \implies |f(x) - L|<\epsilon$.

I was taught that a very long time ago, a *limit* is something you approach very *closely*, but not exactly *equal to*. So what logic rule am I breaking if i take $\epsilon = |f(x) - L|$?

Also, what is the advantage of proving two things are equal by saying they are *epsilon close* to each other? Isn't this really just make it harder than it needs it to be?

**EDIT**

I have also noticed that some other definitions that uses epsilon distance instead of just saying they are equal to each other.

> $f \in R(\alpha)$ on $[a,b] \iff \forall \epsilon >0, \exists$ partition $P$ such that $$U(f,P,\alpha) - L(f,P,\alpha) < \epsilon$$

Now what is wrong with saying

> $f \in R(\alpha)$ on $[a,b] \iff  \exists$ partition $P$ such that $$U(f,P,\alpha) =  L(f,P,\alpha) $$

Comment: I can guarantee you that sometimes showing that $|x-y|<\varepsilon$ is far easier than sohwing directly that $x=y$, specially when $x$ and $y$ are defined as the "limit of something".

Comment: What it means is that for any **given** positive number $p$, we can choose $\epsilon$ such that $0\lt \epsilon \lt p$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas, it is always bigger than $0$?

Comment: Yes, it is always bigger than $0$. But in typical formulations we end up concluding that the quantity $|Q|$ is $\lt \epsilon$, and $|Q|$ can be $0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is really more of an extended comment, rather than an answer.

From the point of view of pure logic, the phrase "$\epsilon > 0$ can be chosen arbitrarily small" simply means "for all $\epsilon > 0$."  That's it.

So why include the "arbitrarily small" part?

The phrase "arbitrarily small" is simply telling the reader how s/he should think about the property involving $\epsilon$.  Namely, it tells the reader that it will be relatively easy to satisfy the property with large values of $\epsilon$, but harder to satisfy it with smaller values of $\epsilon$.  And yet, despite this difficulty when small values of $\epsilon$ are taken, the statement is still true!

> **Example:** Suppose I tell you that for every $\epsilon > 0$, there exists a real number $\delta$ satisfying $0 < \delta^3 < \epsilon$.  You're not sure whether to believe me, so you try examples:
>
> - If $\epsilon = 1$, then there are lots of numbers $\delta$ that make the statement true.  (e.g. every $0 < \delta < 1$ works)
> - If $\epsilon = 100$, then there are **even more** values of $\delta$ that make the statement true. (e.g. every $0 < \delta < 4$ works)
>
> In fact, if you've proven that my statement is true for a given $\epsilon$, then it's also true for all greater $\epsilon' > \epsilon$.  Like, if it's true for $\epsilon = 1$, then it's true for $\epsilon = 2.5, 17, 10000$, etc.
>
> But I said that it's true for **all** $\epsilon > 0$.  That means that we have to look at small values of $\epsilon$, too.  And in these cases, values of $\delta$ that work are less plentiful.
>
> In such a situation, I would say that my statement is true for all $\epsilon >0$, *no matter how small*, to emphasize this point.
>
> **Note,** however, that although my statement is true for all $\epsilon > 0$, no matter how small, it is decidedly **false** for $\epsilon = 0$.

Comment: Okay I have to be honest, out of all the answers it seems like you understand me the most and I am not easiest student to understand.

Comment: SO basically you are saying $\forall \epsilon > 0$ is in some ways, a "without any loss of generality" or some sort?

Comment: If I say that "$\forall \epsilon > 0$, the statement $P_\epsilon$ is true," then I mean just that: The statements $P_1$, $P_{15}$, $P_{0.17}$, etc are all true. The phrase "without loss of generality" (WLOG) means something different. WLOG is a phrase used during a proof to indicate that "If we prove a certain simple case, then the general case will follow."

Comment: Example: If you're trying to prove the example in my above answer, then -- since we proved the case of $\epsilon = 1$, and we also know that the statement will therefore be true for all $\epsilon > 1$ -- we can assume WLOG that $\epsilon < 1$. It then remains to prove that the statement is true for all $0 < \epsilon < 1$. Of course, in this case that doesn't really help us, but in some situations this sort of simplification can really help. In my opinion, though, I think beginners should avoid using the phrase "WLOG" in their own proofs.

Comment: I put "WLOG" in quotations on purpose, but I am trying to connect an analogy. I am saying that by showing it is true for $\forall \epsilon$, no matter how big or small, you have shown for it is true for each $\epsilon$. I know this is a very stupid sentence.

Comment: Again, the words "small" and "large" are purely psychological; they tell you how to intuit what you're doing. You can do analysis just fine without ever using either term. But yes... if you've proven that a statement holds $\forall \epsilon > 0$, then, yes, it certainly is true for EVERY $\epsilon > 0$.

Answer (score 5):

More correctly, if $f(x)$ is a real-valued function defined in a real open interval around a real number $a$ (except possibly **at** $a$) then we say $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=L$ if $$\forall\epsilon>0,\exists\delta>0:0<|x-a|<\delta\implies|f(x)-L|<\epsilon.$$

That $\epsilon$-$\delta$ language means that for any positive $\epsilon$, we can keep $f(x)$ within a distance $\epsilon$ of $L$ simply by making sure that $x$ stays within some distance $\delta>0$ of $a$ (except perhaps if $x=a$). Eliminating the $\epsilon$ and $\delta$ entirely, this means that we can keep $f(x)$ "as close as we like" to $L$, simply by keeping $x$ "close enough" to (but not equal to) $a$.

How close is "close enough"? Well, that will depend on several factors in general, and almost always on how close we'd like $f(x)$ to stay to $L$--if we want to keep $f(x)$ closer to $L$, we may need to keep $x$ closer to $a,$ too.

Note that $x$ is still a variable in this definition--unlike $L$ (and $a$), it is *not* fixed, so we can't simply take $\epsilon=|f(x)-L|.$

Now, if we fixed some $x_0\ne a$ **and** happened to know that $f(x_0)\ne L,$ then we could certainly take $\epsilon=|f(x_0)-L|.$ Then if $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=L,$ we'd know that there was some $\delta>0$ such that $|f(x)-L|<\epsilon$ whenever $0<|x-a|<\delta$--that is, we could keep $f(x)$ closer to $L$ than $f(x_0)$ is, by making sure that $x$ stays within $\delta$ of (but not equal to) $a$. Note that such a $\delta$ will necessarily be less than $|x_0-a|,$ since if not, then $x_0$ is an $x$ that is within $\delta$ of (but not equal to) $a$, yet $|f(x_0)-L|=\epsilon$.

Let me sum up the discussion the previous paragraph: If there is some $x_0\ne a$ with $f(x_0)\ne L$, and we know that $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=L,$ then we can keep $f(x)$ closer to $L$ than $f(x_0)$ is, by making sure that we keep $x$ closer to (but not equal to) $a$ than $x_0$ is by a sufficient amount.

Hopefully that summary doesn't surprise you or confuse you, but let me know if it does.

Does this help clear things up for you?

Comment: Oh I forgot that $f(x)$ is variable. I guess this also kind of answer my edit. But could you spell it out and tell me what is the variable? I don't think the partition $P$ is since once i find that $P$, it is up to only $f$ again?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you mean by $\alpha$, there, but it looks like you're discussing Riemann integrability over $[a,b]$. Consider the function $f(x)=x$ on the interval $[0,1].$ Take any partition $P,$ say into $n$ sub-intervals, with smallest interval length $\ell$. Then $U(f,P)-L(f,P)$ is the sum of the squares of the lengths of the subintervals (draw a picture), so $$U(f,P)-L(f,P)\ge n\ell^2>0.$$

Comment: The definition was retrieved from Baby Rudin. But my question was (let's pretend you never posted your answer for now) why couldn't we just say $U(f,P) = L(f,P)$

Comment: Or with relevance to my question, what's wrong with choosing $\epsilon = U(f,P) - L(f,P)$?

Comment: The reason you can't (or at least shouldn't) just say $U(f,P)=L(f,P)$ is that non-constant functions, like $f(x)=x$, would never satisfy that definition of integrability.

Comment: @sidht: Regarding the problem with requiring $U(f,P)=L(f,P),$ see Andreas's comment. The example I gave above shows that even super-nice functions would fail to be integrable under that altered definition.

Comment: @sidht: As for the reason we can't put $\epsilon=U(f,P)-L(f,P)$, it's because the partition will depend on the choice of $\epsilon>0,$ just as $\delta>0$ did in my answer. The idea of the partition $P$ is that we can choose subintervals that are "narrow enough" so that the difference between the upper and lower sums is "as small as we like." As in my answer, if $P_0$ is a partition such that $U(f,P_0)>L(f,P_0),$ then we **can** put $\epsilon_0=U(f,P_0)-L(f,P_0),$ and if $f$ is Riemann integrable, there is a partition $P$ such that $U(f,P)-L(f,P)<\epsilon_0$. ...

Comment: ... In other words, if the upper sum and lower sum of a Riemann integrable function aren't the same for a given partition, then we can find a partition that makes the upper sum and lower sum closer.

Comment: @anyone, regarding the $f(x) = x$ example, then how does $U(f,P) - L(f,P) < \epsilon$ fixes the problem? Aren't we going to send $\epsilon \to 0$ anyways? Because we have another problem now.

Comment: We are not sending $\epsilon$ anywhere. Rather, we are choosing an arbitrary positive $\epsilon$ which will be **fixed**, then showing that there is some partition $P$ (which depends on the $\epsilon$ we chose), so that the upper and lower sums differ by less than $\epsilon.$ To do this (in my example above), find $n$ sufficiently large so that $\frac1n<\epsilon,$ and let $P$ be the partition of $[0,1]$ into $n$ equal subintervals of length $\ell=\frac1n.$ Then $$U(f,P)-L(f,P)=n\ell^2=\frac1n<\epsilon.$$

Comment: But isn't the goal still make $\epsilon$ small?

Comment: @sidht: Not really. It is to show that we can choose $\epsilon>0$ to be *as small as we like*, and *still* find a partition $P$ to make $U(f,P)$ and $L(f,P)$ differ by less than $\epsilon$. We get our flexibility in $\epsilon$'s size by choosing it in the first step.

Comment: Right and isn't that what the analysts mean when they say *as small as we like (and later send $\epsilon \to 0$)*?

Comment: @sidht: Analysts who say "send $\epsilon\to 0$" are being sloppy, usually because they are in a situation where *they* know they can afford to be. This tends to lead to confusion in people who are newer to the concepts, though, so it's a *terrible* thing to say from a teaching standpoint.

Answer (score 3):

They certainly do not mean you can take $\epsilon=0$. Usually, the statement

> $\epsilon$ can be chosen arbitrarily small

means that whatever property the statement is referring true holds for any $\epsilon>0$. Often this fact is used to take some limit as $\epsilon\to 0^+$ (called the limit from the right as $\epsilon$ goes to $0$).

Comment: What is my mistake in my post then? I know there is something wrong when I chose $\epsilon = |f(x) - L|$

Comment: @sidht I don't know what you're doing. Your definition of limit is correct, but all that is is define what $\lim\limits_{x\to a}f(x)=L$ means. You don't set $\epsilon$ equal to anything in the definition.

Comment: Why not? I know the distance between $f(x)$ and $L$ are epsilon close, and since this is true for each $\epsilon >0$. I chose that $\epsilon$.

Comment: @sidht I'm very confused. It's a definition. You don't "do" anything.

Comment: @sidht when you say "the distance between $f(x)$ and $L$" you already make the crucial mistake. $L$ is a number and $f(x)$ is a function, so there is no such thing as the distance between one and the other. The definition of limits does not claim that the distance between a function and a number is 0. Intuitively what it says is that the value $f(x)$ can be made arbitrarily close to $L$ by making $x$ arbitrarily close to $a$, where $a$ is where the limit is computed. Formally, the definition of limit is the definition of limit.

Comment: @IttayWeiss, right what I meant was *the distance between $f$ and $L$* can be made arbitrarily close when $x$ is close to $a$

Comment: @sidht Not *when $x$ is close to $a$*, but *by setting $x$ sufficiently close to $a$*

Comment: @AlexBecker, are you trying to correct me by saying it is *very close* instead of *close* because that's usually what I mean when I say *close*.

Comment: @sidht you totally miss the point. There is no distance between $f$ and $L$. The quantity $|f(x)-L|$ can be made arbitrarily small by setting the quantity $|x-a|$ to be sufficiently small. It's all about approximations.

Comment: Am I allowed to replace the word *quantity* with *distance*?

Comment: @sidht The distance between $f(x)$ and $L$ is the quantity $|f(x)-L|$, and similarly the distance between $x$ and $a$ is the quantity $|x-a|$.

Comment: @AlexBecker, yeah that's what meant. Isn't that what I was saying when I said "the distance between $f(x)$ and $L$"?

Comment: @sidht We're getting confused between when you are referring to the value of $f$ at some fixed $x$ and when you are referring to the function $f$.

Comment: Oh you guys were thinking that I was saying the distance between a number and a fluctuating (maybe not the best adj here) function?